# Only exception info printed when using sys.stdout

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I have print code that looks like this:

```
a_dict = {'data': 'y'}


try:
    raise KeyError
except KeyError:
    logging.info(f'yo {a_dict}')
    logging.exception(f'ye {a_dict}')
```

Which results in

```
{"message": "yo {'data': 'y'} some_location:29", "severity": "INFO"}
{"message": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/some_fake_location\", line 27, in a_method\n    raise KeyError\nKeyError some_location:30", "severity": "ERROR"}
```

I make a `handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)` which then receives my format.

How do I make it receive my message on top of the exception info. I do want to keep the StreamHandler since it used to assign the formatter.

Answer (score 0):

Was a silly mistake in formatting where I didn't include the message only the exc_info.